# How do I log queries for just one database?

Tags: mysql, logging

I have a number of databases running on a server.

I'd like to log queries going to just one database (I have a wiki on the same box and I don't care about wiki queries).

I've done some googling, but can't find the answer I'm looking for.

Are there any settings I can use to limit the entries in my MySQL log, so that only queries to a single database are logged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The longer answer is that with a bunch of work, you can monitor the log for new input, drop stuff you don't want, keep what you do, and regularly recycle the log. It seems based on [this discussion](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/35680071/has-anybody-convinced-mysqld-yet-to-log-to-syslog--query-log.aspx) (towards the end, post entitled "...Have you tried the normal usage of a named pipe?") that simply trying to specify a named pipe as the logfile doesn't work. They don't specify why, though, so you can try it and see for yourself. Good luck!